# iOS Tests and UITests Confusion

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, provisioning-profile, xcode-ui-testing

When I create an iOS AppTests and AppUITests target, i see some difference.

- AppTest target setting has an extra option "Allow testing host application APIs", But AppUITests target has no such option. So what does it do and why they are different?

[image: Tests]
[image: UITests]

- AppTests target does not ask for any provisioning profile, but AppUITests targets give error if provisioning profile is not set. I know "Automatically manage Signing" might fix this issue. But i don't want to allow Xcode to upload some bundles, certs & profiles into my Server on its own (to be clear whats going on). I need to know why its asking for AppUITest but not for AppTest. Is it because UITests need real device installation?

[image: Tests]
[image: UITests]

How can I get rid of this extra bundle id, profile management hassle for AppUITests target?

Guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Unit test is for testing small portion, standalone part of your code, while UITest is automated to run through UI of your app to test the whole flow, they are different

Comment: so do I need a different bundle and profile to run ui test on actual device?

Comment: i dont think so, you can just let it use automated provisioning i suppose

Comment: what do u mean by automated provisioning? u meant by enabling "Automatically manage signing"? which will eventually create certs, profiles etc in server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From last few days I am also searching such type of things . There are two type of testing

1. Unit testing
2. UI testing

Most probably you already awared from this two types.

For your first point see below image provide by [WWDC Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/409/),

[image]

Unit test use **Host App** that means your app coding during the testing time. But UI testing UI test bundle is loaded into **Target app** which is different from the Host app.

As I done **R&D** here

- Testtests is for unit test file and,
- TestUItests is for UI test.

For 2nd point I don't have idea because I never tried this.

If you got some better result then me Please update me too. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Lets wait for experts opinion.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan In this doc, [Clean swifter](http://cleanswifter.com/xcode-ui-tests-review/), As here is mentained `The documentation for Xcode UI tests is still light`, So why actually we use UI test cases Because until UI is not completely work properly then there is no use of creating UI test case because on every change in UI you need to make new test case and IF UI test case is working properly as we develped it then why we create UI test case to check. Sorry for interpreting but I wanted to now UI test is weak then why we use it. Hope you don't mide with my ques. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually ui test is required by my company. I think xocode provided ui test is preferred until now. Can you suggest any better tool for ui test?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Apple provides Testing from `x-code 7` and it is enhanced in `x-code 8` before it there is no support of testing provided by apple framework. So developer use some third party like [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) which is most powerful at that time. I don't know right now which framework is more powerful. As a suggestion, if apple providing you framework than prefer it. Apple doesn't like there developers and user go out of there scope thats why when some framework get famous then apple create same apple framework in its native.